# Jquery image Gallery with Accordion Caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am looking for jquery image gallery plugin with accordion caption in right side, like this([please See](http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/)).
I searched a lot but didn't find one. I found some relevant plugin like jQuery.slideBanjo([please See](http://www.gbws.ru/content/downloads/sbanjodemo/)) and Featured Content Slider Using jquery-ui([please See](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/)). but they are not good.

Please can someone tell me a good plugin they know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one out

[Slidorion](http://www.slidorion.com/)

It's got both things slider and accordion.

Comment: that was the thing i was looking for, with few modifications it should work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are several plugins that should get you going:

- [Elegant Accordion with jQuery and CSS3](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/elegant-accordion-with-jquery-and-css3/)
- [Create A jQuery Accordion Image Slider For Your Website](http://www.aoclarkejr.com/tutorial-jquery-accordion-slider.html)
- [jQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)
- [jQuery Easy Accordion Plugin](http://www.madeincima.it/download/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/)
- [How to Create Accordion Menu (CSS3+jQuery) (Tutorial)](http://designmodo.com/jquery-accordion-menu/)
- [jQuery – Accordion Image Menu Plugin](http://web-argument.com/2011/03/07/jquery-accordion-image-menu-plugin/)

For those accordion plugins that display text you could replace it with your gallery images.

Hopefully, it helps.